# SQL Left Join Problem (All lines is not coming)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, missing-data

**The tables are as below:**

Users Table (Table Name: **users**) :

[users table]

[image: 1]

Friends Table (Table Name: **friends**) :

[friends table]

[image: 2]

**My Sql Code:**

```
SELECT
    friend_id,
    friend_adding_id,
    friend_added_id,
    user_id,
    user_name
FROM friends
LEFT JOIN users ON friends.friend_added_id = users.user_id
WHERE
    friend_adding_id = 1
    OR friend_added_id = 1
    AND friend_confirm = 1
ORDER BY friends.friend_id DESC
LIMIT 1, 10
```

**Leaving the column below:**

[Leaving column]

[image: 4]

How can I fix this missing query? Please help me.

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "missing query"?

Comment: My sql code is not working as it should. 
As a result, 1 line of missing data is returned. The red marked place (question mark) does not come.

Answer (score 0):

first you are missing a row not a column or not a query, second its because of and /or priorities. And has higher priority than OR , for you logic to work properly, you have to give Or higher priority by using parenthesis:

```
SELECT
    friend_id,
    friend_adding_id,
    friend_added_id,
    user_id,
    user_name
FROM friends
LEFT JOIN users ON friends.friend_added_id = users.user_id
WHERE
    (friend_adding_id = 1 OR friend_added_id = 1) -- < like this
    AND friend_confirm = 1
ORDER BY friends.friend_id DESC
LIMIT 1, 10
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is still no last line of the query. A total of 7 rows of results should be returned, but 6 rows of results are returned.

Comment: @PhpMaster you only have 6 rows in friends table , why you expect 7 rows?

Comment: Look at the last row in the friends table, you can see. Number 1 in the first 5 entries in the Friends table added other members as friends. In the last row, number 7 added the number 1 as a friend. Therefore.